# Erro sem solução

Tags: delphi, windows

Boa Tarde pessoal fiquei a semana inteiro quebrando cabeça com uma aplicação e não consegui resolver, eu pago quem me ajudar sem problema... Pra explicar melhor fiz um video e postei no facebook...

OBs: em algumas maquinas funciona normal e em outras não, ja formatei, ja fiz de tudo...Ja testei em umas 10 maquinas, algumas funcionam e outras não, não descobrir o porque, todas que testei foi com windows 7 32 e 64 aleatoriamente

linnk https://youtu.be/2lvW1g5-sOE

Comment: Alguma diferença de antivírus nas máquinas? Sandbox algo assim?

Comment: Muito difícil descobrir o que pode ser, já tive problemas no passado onde o programador anterior, que fez o sistema, instalou o .exe no servidor e mapeou as unidades de rede das outras máquinas apontando para ele, fazendo o carregando remoto através de um atalho nas máquinas clientes. Resolvi deixando o .exe na maquina cliente, como costumo fazer sempre. Mas não tem como saber. Na minha experiência, erros de memória são os mais complicados de descobrir para quem esta olhando de fora.

Comment: Tenta utilizar o EurekaLog, pode ser que exiba mais informações

Comment: Já tentou fazer um Debug na máquina onde apresenta o erro? Instala o Delphi e executa no modo de Debug, de repente você consiga identificar a linha que está causando.

Answer (score 0):

Tivemos um problema misterioso assim também.
Dá uma olhada em sua **Midas.dll** substitua por outra, de uma máquina que esteja funcionando.

Boa sorte.